# How to use a value in switch case?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I pretty new to C# programming so recently I was assigned to do a assignment to calculate the "AverageSpeed" and then match it against the "maxSpeed".

I have issue with the "maxSpeed" as no matter what value I key in I will get a "You are within the speed limit" where I know I should not have receive such a message. I suspect they are using the value of "maxSpeed" of 0 not the max speed in the case.

The program is all about requesting the user for the driver name, the type of vehicle and the travel distance with duration in minutes to find out whether driver has exceed the maximum allowable speed.

Please advise.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(txtDuration.Text);
    double miles = Convert.ToInt32(txtDistance.Text);
    double hours = minutes / 60;
    double AverageSpeed = GetMPH(hours, miles);

    Object itemSelect = (Object)cboCarType.SelectedItem;
    string carType = itemSelect.ToString();

    int maxSpeed =0;
    switch (carType)
    {
        case "Sedan":
            maxSpeed = 100;
            break;
        case "Wagon":
            maxSpeed = 90;
            MessageBox.Show("Wagon");
            break;
        case "Truck":
            maxSpeed = 50;
            break;
        case "Van":
            maxSpeed = 60;
            break;
        case "Bus":
            maxSpeed = 50;
            break;
        case "Tractor trailer":
            maxSpeed = 30;
            break;
    }

    if (AverageSpeed > maxSpeed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have exceed the maximun speed!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are within the speed limit!");
    }

}

double GetMPH(double miles, double hours) 
{
    double GetMPH = miles / hours;
    return GetMPH;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through the code?

Comment: The debugger should tell you everything you need to know here. Set a breakpoint before the switch statement, check the values of the important variables and which code path it follows in the switch statement.

Comment: add a double cast to your hours calculation and see if that solves the issue,  double hours = (double)minutes / 60;

Comment: Evan Trimboli, the program works fine. It should be a logical error.

Comment: JP, I am still looking into it

Comment: Fajibour, I will do it and keep you inform!

Comment: Who is the down voter ?

Comment: @MrTeo i check your code you pass param to `GetMPH` function misplace pass `GetMPH(miles, hours); insted of GetMPH(hours, miles);`. And look at your function `double GetMPH(double miles, double hours)`.

Comment: Even after changing to GetMPH(miles,hours) I get "You have exceed the maximum speed" regardless of what I write.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is nonsense. The answers are upvotes and appear legitimate but there is no question to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your carType string which is not being set properly.
Change `itemSelect.ToString()` to `itemSelect.Text`

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(txtDuration.Text);
    double miles = Convert.ToInt32(txtDistance.Text);
    double hours = minutes / 60;
    double AverageSpeed = GetMPH(miles, hours);

    Object itemSelect = (Object)cboCarType.SelectedItem;
    string carType = itemSelect.Text;

    int maxSpeed =0;
        switch (carType)
        {
            case "Sedan":
                maxSpeed = 100;
                break;
            case "Wagon":
                maxSpeed = 90;
                MessageBox.Show("Wagon");
                break;
            case "Truck":
                maxSpeed = 50;
                break;
            case "Van":
                maxSpeed = 60;
                break;
            case "Bus":
                maxSpeed = 50;
                break;
            case "Tractor trailer":
                maxSpeed = 30;
                break;
        }
         if (AverageSpeed > maxSpeed)
        MessageBox.Show("You have exceed the maximun speed!");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("You are within the speed limit!");

}

double GetMPH(double miles, double hours) 
{
    double GetMPH = miles / hours;
    return GetMPH;
}
```

UPDATE:
You can also use following code to get carType.

```
//Object itemSelect = (Object)cboCarType.SelectedItem; //Remove this line
string carType = cboCarType.SelectedItem.Text;
```

And change your GetMPH function call to GetMPH(miles, hours)

Comment: After changing the carType string, I got this error                                    "Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I tried "string carType = cboCarType.SelectedItem.Text;" before opening this thread but it only gave me another error. Which is "Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Can you please mentioned whether it is a winforms code or asp.net code? I am assuming this is an asp.net application problem.

Answer (score 1):

Step through the code and find out what the values for AverageSpeed and maxSpeed are.  I suspect, based on the description of your error, that AverageSpeed is always zero.

Change your `switch` to a function, like this:

```
public int MaxSpeed(string carType) 
{
   switch (carType)
    {
        case "Sedan": return 100;
        case "Wagon": return 90;
        case "Truck": return 50;
        case "Van": return 60;
        case "Bus": return 50
        case "Tractor trailer": return 30;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will allow you to unit test the function separately and prove that it works.

Comment: Hello, I got 6 of this error "Error 1 Since 'Debugging.Form1.btnSubmit_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"

Answer (score 1):

Probably the switch statement does not update the maxSpeed to the selected value.
Place a breakpoint at the switch statement to see the value of carType.

Comment: Not if his result is always "you are within the speed limit," unless AverageSpeed is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are done with below code :

```
int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(txtDuration.Text);
double miles = Convert.ToInt32(txtDistance.Text);
double hours = minutes / 60;
double AverageSpeed = GetMPH(hours, miles);
```

Replace your with below code:

```
double minutes = Convert.ToDouble(txtDuration.Text);
double miles = Convert.ToDouble(txtDistance.Text);
double hours = minutes / 60;
double AverageSpeed = GetMPH(miles, hours);
```

**And make sure you get correct selected value in your `string carType`.**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @MrTeo i check your code you pass wrong param to `GetMPH` function. **And first understand what ans is posted and do down vote.**

Comment: After following your instuction, whatever I typed became You have exceed the maximun speed!

Comment: @MrTeo May i know your variable value `double minutes, double miles, string carType`. So, i can you help much better way.

Comment: @MrTeo Have you got the solution ?

Comment: SmootherSilent, Firstly I would like to thank you for your help! but I still do not get the solution

Comment: @MrTeo please give your seniors that can i check at my end.

Comment: What do you mean give seniors?

Comment: what you pass in `double minutes, double miles, string carType` to check your `AverageSpeed > maxSpeed` condition ?

Comment: I do not get what you're trying to say.

Comment: I need your `double minutes, double miles, string carType` variables value to check `AverageSpeed > maxSpeed condition` at my end. Now, you got it or not.

Comment: As stated I followed your instruction but then my program will only show 1 answer no matter what I typed.

Comment: So, I think you have check your code why same print every time. Please accept answer if it's useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could print the carType in you code above the switch statement.
For example

**MessageBox.Show(carType);**

This way you can check if the switch statement is working.
e.g. is carType really a sedan as expected?

Debugging and setting a breakpoint is of course also possible.